# Is there a way I can find out if a string in C# does not contain the numbers & characters 0-9 and A-Z?

Tags: c#

I have seen some kind of regular expression tests but how can I check if a string does not contain any of the 0-9 numbers or A-Z characters?

Comment: with a regular expression! What have you seen?

Comment: Any digit or letter, or precisely the ones you listed? Any case or only uppercase?

Comment: Marilou, is `ö` a letter or not ?

Comment: It would need to be not a letter. I want to catch if my string has something other than any combination of 0-9 and A-Z.

Comment: In that case `IsLetterOrDigit()` is probably not the right filter.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need a regex:

```
string s = ...
bool hasLetterOrDigit = s.Any(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));

bool onlyLetterOrDigit = s.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

The `IsLetterOrDigit()` function uses the Unicode classification ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit.aspx)).

If you want precise control:

```
string s = ...
string allowedChars = "abcdefABCDEF0123456789";

bool onlyAllowedChar = s.All(c => allowedChars.Contains(c));
```

Comment: But I want to check if inside the string there is something that is not an uppercase letter or digit.

Comment: Although this is fine and very efficient, what letters does `IsLetterOrDigit` include? I assume not only `"A-Z"` but also lowercase letters etc. From MSDN: UppercaseLetter, LowercaseLetter, TitlecaseLetter, ModifierLetter, OtherLetter, or DecimalDigitNumber

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Not only also lowercase letters, but every single Unicode letter in the world. Not just [A..Z].

Comment: @TimSchmelter - you're right, the 'best' solution will depend on circumstance and use-case. The `Any()` approach is easily adaptable though. I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

Try it using [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

```
bool Exists=Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[^A-Z0-9]+");
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to find if something that is not 0-9 and A-Z exists. I think your code looks for a match the other way.

Comment: right..Fount it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).. Thanks for the correction..

Answer (score 1):

something like...

```
if ((Regex.IsMatch(value, "[^A-Z0-9]+")
{
   //do something
}
```

Edit: Changed to match Matt's suggestion.

Comment: or `(Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[A-Z0-9]")`

Comment: You don't need the `if !`, the `^` at the start of the regex means do *not* match any of these characters.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be `[^A-Z0-9]+`

Comment: @Key. I want to catch if my string has something other than any combination of 0-9 and A-Z. If my string contains a "g" will that be considered not a match using the Regex?

Comment: @Marilou if the string must contain only characters which are **not** A-Z or 0-9, then use this regex `^[^A-Z0-9]+$`